# Absolute convergence question.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if $\sum (a_n) $ is an absolutely convergent series, then $\sum (a_n^p) $ is also absolutely convergent for every integer $p\geq 1 $ clearly this holds when $p=1 $

Lets consider when $p>1 $

since $lim_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n) =0 $ there must exist some term denote it $|(a_{n_{K}})|$ such that $ \forall k>K $ every term of $|(a_{n_{k}})| <1.  $

Clearly $|(a^{p}_{n_{k}})|< |(a_{n_{k}})| <1.  $   $\forall p >1$

However $\lim |(a_{n_{k}})| =0$ so by comparision test  $\lim|(a^{p}_{n_{k}})| =0 $?

Comment: You even can can conclude directly the series $\sum |a_n|^p$ converges if  $\sum |a_n|$ does.

Comment: How do you make such an argument? without making an argument on  p?

Comment: Notation: You can remove those parentheses. Also, $a_{n_k}$ looks like a subsequence, which is not what you want. And it should be $|a_n|^p\le |a_n|,$ not strict inequality.

Comment: I didn't intend for it to be a subsequence I just wanted to choose far enough along in the sequence that it was strictly less than 1 but I don't think I did it well... it doesn't hold for all terms cause it's bigger if $a_n >1 $

Comment: Since $\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n$ is absolutely convergent, we have $|a_n|\leq 1$ for any $n>N$. 
This implies $\sum_{n>N}|a_n|^p \leq \sum_{n>N}|a_n| \leq C $, so $\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n^p$ is absolutely convergent since $\sum_{n=1}^{N}|a_n|^p$ is just a number.

Comment: @Faust: Because $|a_n|<1$ if $n$is large enough, hence $|a_n|^p\le |a_n|$ if $p\ge 1$.

Comment: Yeah i figured it out from Jacks post (its what i was trying to say in the first place anyway) he just said it alot better. Thanks all.